# How to Migrate a large project from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3

I want migrate large project to vue 3 , but I didn't do it before. Is it right if I ll start with update file package.json? its my file(if its right. how can I do it its right. I ll be glad instruction). I already try update @vue/cli till 5.x with command nom install --save-dev @vue/cli@5.x , change version vue(but because of tiptop its not work)

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^4.5.9",
    "accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.9.8",
    "element-theme-chalk": "^2.14.1",
    "element-ui": "^2.3.6",
    "element-ui-el-table-draggable": "^1.2.10",
    "fuse-js-latest": "^3.1.0",
    "fuse.js": "^6.4.6",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "inputmask": "^5.0.5",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.12",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "svgo": "^2.8.0",
    "svgo-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "tippy.js": "^6.2.7",
    "tiptap": "^1.31.0",
    "tiptap-extensions": "^1.34.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "v-file-upload": "^3.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.2.6",
    "vue-affix": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-at": "2.x",
    "vue-dadata": "^1.4.10",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9",
    "vue-simple-svg": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-svg-inline-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "vue-svg-sprite": "^2.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.5.1",
    "wialon": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "^4.1.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-element-ui": "~1.1.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-lodash": "~0.1.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-svg-sprite": "~1.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-svg-sprite-loader": "~1.0.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwindcss": "~0.1.1",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.6",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.2.6"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can't easily do that because of third-party libs. You need to check your options for each of them before moving further. In some cases V3 compatibility mode may work to use V2 some libs that don't have a counterpart but you shouldn't really count on that as it may break depending on a lib. " I already try update @vue/cli till 5.x" - this isn't directly tied to Vue version

Comment: We're in the same situation. Vue2 + Element-UI create a deadlock as Element-UI won't work in Vue3, and you cannot upgrade to Element-Plus as it won't work in Vue2. We do have Microfrontends and I can confirm that Vue2 MFE can work along side to Vue3 MFE, so it might be our only way.

Answer (score 1):

it's actually easy than you may think and you can do it incrementally in terms of codebase. Yes, you'll need to do some set-up around your packages but if you follow the instructions in the docs it's very easy.

here's the doc https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html. You can follow the step-by-step advice in the doc. A very good thing is your guess is correct.  **Migration starts from the package.json file**. Best of luck

Comment: I tried to follow the migration path for a large project (2M lines, ~5 years of dev). It took me about a month to fine tune all tools and libraries only to find out that our main components library - Element-UI won't work with `@vue/compat` 

Comment: you can try this tool https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-migration